# httpd forward traffic from a url to another machine on same lan virtual host

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd

I'm running HTTPD on a CentOs 6 server.

I have 2 servers on the same LAN as eachother.  I only have 1 IP address.  I have 2 domains pointing at the router and I want example1.com handled by server 1 and example2.com handled by server 2.  The router can forwards PORT 80 to server 1.  I need server 1 to forward traffic directed at example2.com to server 2.

It needs to not interfere with other virtual host targets that look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried it using mod_rewrite like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* http://192.168.1.60$0 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I load up example2.com in the browser, it tries to load 192.168.1.60, which I can't see because the browser is not on the same LAN as the 2 servers.

How do I do this?

Comment: is `NameVirtualHost *:80` defined somewhere in your config ?

Comment: @krisFR I was missing the NameVirtualHost definition.  I added it, but it still doesn't work. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Great. So now your vHost no more overlap. `but when I load up example2.com in the browser, it tries to load 192.168.1.60` Is this not what you want ? This is what you config says. If you have Lan subnet issue we are not able to help with infos you provided...describe your network config, routing...(Also note that you said `on same lan` in your original question title, but `not on the same LAN` in the question. Please try to clarify)

Comment: @krisFR thanks for helping make this clear.  I have 2 server on the same LAN as eachother and I need to be able to load webpage from each of them from outside of the LAN.

Comment: You want ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.

Comment: @wurtel You're right, that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found that ended up working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.60/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.60/
</VirtualHost>
```

This uses a httpd module called mod_proxy which was enabled by default on my instillation.